# I need help making pandas perform better with dataframe interactions

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas

I'm a newbie and have been studying pandas for a few days, and started my first project with it. I wanted to use it to create a product stock prediction timeline for the current month.

Basically I get the stock and predicted daily reduction and trace a line from today to the end of the month with the predicted stock. Also, if there is a purchase order to be delivered on day XYZ, I add the delivery amount on that day.

I have a dataframe that contain's the stock for today and the predicted daily redutcion for this month

```
ITEM    STOCK    DAILY_DEDUCTION
A       1000     20
B       2000     15
C       800      8
D       10000    100
```

And another dataframe that contains pending purchase orders and amount that will be delivered.

```
ITEM    DATE         RECEIVING_AMOUNT
A       2018-05-16   20
B       2018-05-23   15
A       2018-05-17   8
D       2018-05-29   100
```

I created this loop to iterate through the dataframe and do the following:

1. subtract the DAILY_DEDUCTION for the item
2. if the date is the same as a purchase order date, then add the RECEIVING_AMOUNT

   ```
   df_dates = pd.date_range(start=today, end=endofmonth, freq='D')

   temptable = []

   for row in df_stock.itertuples(index=True):
       predicted_stock= getattr(row, "STOCK")
       item = getattr(row, "ITEM")

       for date in df_dates:
           date_format = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
           predicted_stock = predicted_stock - getattr(linha, "DAILY_DEDUCTION")
           order_qty = df_purchase_orders.loc[(df_purchase_orders['DATE'] == date_format)
                                            & (df_purchase_orders['ITEM'] == item), 'RECEIVING_AMOUNT']
           if len(df_purchase_orders.index) > 0:
               predicted_stock = predicted_stock + order_qty.item()
           lista = [date_format, item, int(predicted_stock)]
           temptable.append(lista)
   ```

And... well, it did the job, but it's quite slow. I run this on 100k rows give or take, and was hoping to find some insight on how I can solve this problem in a way that performs better?

Comment: `For` loops in Python are very slow and can generally be avoided when using Pandas.

Comment: You probably can merge the two data frames by joining on date and use `apply`